# Past tense means politeness?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tenses, expression-choice, rules

Questions asked using past tense, some examples like: "Would you mind...?", "Could you please...?", "Should I do...?", "Did you want...?"

It seems people are using past tense in these sort of questions, when the correct tense grammatically is present tense.

Why is that?

Is this a hint of being polite or humble? Is there a grammar rule for this setup? Or is this wrong grammar but usual usage?

Comment: Why the downvote and closing votes? Enlightenment me how you think this is not related to English language and its usage?

Comment: Look up [*modals*](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/will-would-shall-should) in any English grammar  website to get a fuller and better picture. The topic of [modals](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/modalintro.html) is very vast, quite complicated for learners, and needs to be taught properly.

Comment: The following verbs: *will* / *would*, *can* / *could*, *may* / *might*, *shall* and *should* are modals, the verb that follows is in the infinitive without "to" . E.G *Will you take this to Mr. Brown**, *Would you take this to Mr Brown?*, *Do you mind taking this to Mr Brown?* and *Would you mind taking this to Mr Brown?* all mean the same, and all refer to the present, "now". It *may* look related to the  "past" but the requests are made in the present.

Comment: Compare: "May I close the window?", "Can I close the window?", "Could I close the window?", Shall I close the window? and "Would you mind terribly, if I closed the window?" all of these requests are polite, some more than others. Which do you think are the most polite, and why?

Comment: Thanks @Mari-LouA, love to see you answering instead of commenting. To answer your question, the "past" tense forms are more polite, and that is exactly my question, WHY "past" tense? The question is not asking about what are modal verbs, is asking why the "past" tense form shows more politeness? This is not being addressed in all the answer/comments so far. And forget about modal verbs, I also gave an example of usual shop assistants saying "Did you want any help?" instead of "Do you want any help?". Clearly Do/Did is not modal verb.

Comment: With all due respect, I only see: *"Did you want...?* cited in your question. Excluding the last example in the comments: *Did you want any help?* all the other examples employ modal verbs. *Could I help you?* Is not asking whether I gave you assistance, it is asking about "now".  You can edit and clarify your question, but do not ignore the possibility that we have here are modal verbs, these auxiliary verbs are often used to make polite requests in the present.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes most of my examples are modal verbs, but even that, both the present tense and past tense forms are modal verbs, still the unanswered question is why the past tense form is more polite than the present tense form?

Answer (score 1):

The tense used when asking such questions is not the simple past tense, rather it is the conditional tense, which is used "to speculate about what could happen, what might have happened, and what we wish would happen." (this is a quote from this website that breaks down the conditional very well http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/conditional/ )

When you are asking someone to do something for you, the conditional is used because you want them to do something for you though it has not been done, and you are not sure whether or not it will be done. It's just something you wish would happen.

Though for the last example "Did you want to..." I think it's more commonly expressed as "Would you like to?"

Hope this answered your question.

Comment: Thanks. The only occurrence to me of the conditional tense is when using together with "If" sentences. Not sure what you said applies here. I can wait for other posters' comments. The last one I was thinking "Did you want something?" or "Did you want my help? like usually when you go into a shop what a shop assistance will say.

Comment: @user1589188 You may be right. But, only most cases of the conditional in English begin with If, not all. I think with questions the rule is a bit different.

Comment: It's better to call this the modal use of *would*, the past tense of *will*.  *Modal* means that the verb conveys something other than time, person, or number.  Here it's a polite, reserved way to ask a favor or disguise a command as a request.

Comment: Thanks @deadrat for agreeing such use is for politeness reason. But you are merely pointing out people use it that way, just because, period. This is exactly what my question is asking, why past tense means politeness? Without loss of meaning, same sentence can be constructed using present tense. To make it more polite, some other languages will either make the sentence longer by throwing in more polite words or add in special polite phrase at the end of the sentence. English, uses past tense, why?

Comment: @user1589188 I'm going to guess that you're confusing the past tense (which is a verb form) with the meaning of past time (which is but one use of the past tense). Please forgive me if I've made an erroneous assumption.  The "softening" aspect of the past tense of will (i.e., *would*) is very old.  The *OED* can date written examples to the year 888.  Let me emphasize that this usage (called *modal*) isn't about time at all. There really isn't much more reason than that people "use it that way" and have for a very long time. Perhaps the answer may be found in Old English.